# How to make img blocks to fill 100% width screen and get fit to all resolutions?

Tags: html, css

How i can make img blocks that fit to any resolutions and always fill 100% width of screen?

Is it possiblie to make it to look always like on the picture below?

I need to make it like on this pic (4 blocks in one row):

[image]

Code:

HTML

```
            <section id="realizacje" data-speed="10" data-type="background">
              <article>
                  <div class="pasek_suwakow" style="top: 190px;">
                    <a href="#marki"><div class="suwak_gora"></div></a>
                    <a href="#manifest"><div class="suwak"></div></a>
                    <a href="#wspolpraca"><div class="suwak"></div></a>
                    <a href="#realizacje"><div class="suwak_wybrane"></div></a>
                    <a href="#kontakt"><div class="suwak_dol"></div></a>
                  </div>

                    <div id="realizacjebody">
                        <div id="realizacjeheadline">WYBRANE REALIZACJE</div>
                        <div id="przerywnik_realizacje"></div>
                    </div>


                    <div id="wybranerealizacje">

                        <div class="realizacjawrapper">
                            <div class="realizacjaimg"><img src="images/zephyr1.jpg"></div>
                            <div class="realizacjatext"><b class="regular">Zephyr</b><br></br>Ogrzewacz powietrza na pelet zaprojektowany na potrzeby marki MZ. <br><br>Wzór opracowany w 2013 roku.</div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="realizacjawrapper">
                            <div class="realizacjaimg"><img src="images/cedar1.jpg"></div>
                            <div class="realizacjatext"><b class="regular">Cedar</b><br></br>Kominek na drewno MZ z płaszczem wodnym.<br></br>Opracowany z myślą o małym domu lub jako komplementarne źródło ciepła.</div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="realizacjawrapper">
                            <div class="realizacjaimg"><img src="images/idro18.jpg"></div>
                            <div class="realizacjatext"><b class="regular">IdroBox Evo 18</b><br></br>Klasyczny kocioł na pelet marki MZ.<br></br></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="realizacjawrapper">
                            <div class="realizacjaimg"><img src="images/idro22.jpg"></div>
                            <div class="realizacjatext"><b class="regular">IdroBox Evo 22</b><br></br>Klasyczny kocioł na pelet marki MZ<br></br>Młodszy ale silniejszy brat IdroBox Evo 18</div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="realizacjawrapper">
                            <div class="realizacjaimg"><img src="images/idro32.jpg"></div>
                            <div class="realizacjatext"><b class="regular">IdroBox Evo 32</b><br></br>Klasyczny kocioł na pelet marki MZ<br></br>Najmocniejszy płaszcz wodny w całym zestawieniu MZ. Moc w formie.</div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="realizacjawrapper">
                            <div class="realizacjaimg"><img src="images/MZT1.jpg"></div>
                            <div class="realizacjatext"><b class="regular">AirBox 22</b><br></br>Ogrzewacz powietrza opracowany na potrzeby marki MZT.<br></br>Przeznaczony do ogrzewania przestrzeni przemysłowych i użytkowych.</div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="realizacjawrapper">
                            <div class="realizacjaimg"><img src="images/verbier.jpg"></div>
                            <div class="realizacjatext"><b class="regular">Verbier</b><br></br>Kocioł na pelet marki MZ.<br></br> Forma urządzenia RTV/AGD pozwala na umieszczenie w przestrzeni mieszkalnej lub kuchennej. Nasza mała rewolucja w ogrzewnictwie.</div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="realizacjawrapper">
                            <div class="realizacjaimg"><img src="images/aria3.jpg"></div>
                            <div class="realizacjatext"><b class="regular">Aria 4D</b><br></br>Ogrzewacz powietrza na pelet marki MZ.<br></br>Konstrukcja umożliwia rozprowadzenie ciepła po domu przy pomocy kanałów wentylacyjnych.</div>
                        </div>

                    </div>

               <div class="strzalkawdol" style="top: 750px;"><a href="#kafelobraz3"><img src="images/przejdz.png" alt="Nebiolo"><div class="przejdz"></div></a></div>

              </article>
            </section>
```

CSS

```
            #realizacje article{
            height: 658px;
            position: absolute; 
            top: 100px;
            width: 100%; 
            text-align: center;
            font-size: 21px;
            color: #777777;
            font-family: sspro-light;
            }

            #realizacjebody{
            width: 100%;
            position: absolute;
            }


            #realizacjeheadline{
            margin-bottom: 10px;
            text-align: center;
            position: relative;
            font-size: 14px;
            }

            #wybranerealizacje{
            /* width: 1220px; */
            width: 100%;
            position: relative;
            top: 80px;
            margin: 0 auto;
            height: 800px;
            background: green;
            }

            .realizacjawrapper{
            width: 300px;
            height: 376px;
            position: relative;
            float: left;
            }

            .realizacjaimg{
            position: absolute;
            max-width: 100%; 
            max-height: 100%;
            overflow: hidden;
            }

            .realizacjatext{
            position: absolute;
            background: #36657b;
            color: white;
            width: 280px;
            height: 50%;
            margin-top: 56%;
            font-size: 14px;
            text-align: left;
            padding: 10px;
            }
```

Comment: does it have to fill the entire screen height to or can it overflow the bottom with a scrollbar?

Comment: In order to make sure that your code works for all resolution always specify the div's width and height in percentage relative to outer div. Also look up maintaining aspect ratio in HTML images, in order to ensure that aspect ration is always maintained

Comment: Do you want four columns of images in the mobile version as well? Or does the amount of columns change if you resize your browser window?

Comment: It should always fill whole width, and always 4 images in one row.

Answer (score 1):

You can float your images to the left inside a 100% with wrapper div. Then give them `width:25%;`and `height:auto;`

See this  **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/4AVA8/4/)**

HTML:

```
<div id="top">WYBRANE REALIZACJE</div>
<div id="img_wrapper">
     <img src="http://placekitten.com/200/300"/>
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/g/200/300"/>
     <img src="http://placekitten.com/200/300"/>
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/g/200/300"/>
     <img src="http://placekitten.com/200/300"/>
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/g/200/300"/>
     <img src="http://placekitten.com/200/300"/>
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/g/200/300"/>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#top{
    height:150px;
    width:100%;
    line-height:150px;
    text-align:center;
}
#img_wrapper{
    width:100%;
}
img{
    display:block;
    float:left;
    width:25%;
    height:auto;
}
```

To adapt this solution to your code, you just need to add `width:25%;` to `.realizacjawrapper`
and this

```
.realizacjaimg img{
    width:100%;
    height:auto
    display:block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For each img give height and width in percentages instead of pixels
If u want 4 imgs i a row width should be 25%
If u want 5 images in column height should be 20%
Of commonly decide number of images in it simple create a table with that num of rows n colums

Answer (score 0):

If you just want 4 images in a row, you can set the width of each image to 25%, which adds up to 100% in total:

```
<div class="image">
    <div class="image__item">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/300x500" alt="Placeholder">
    </div>
    <div class="image__item">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/300x500" alt="Placeholder">
    </div>
    <!-- ... more images ... -->
</div>
```

Then you just need to set the width of each inner div to 25% and float them (don't forget the clearfix if you are using float):

```
.image__item {
    width: 25%; /* four images in a row: 25 * 4 = 100 */
    float: left; /* display in one line */
}
```

To make sure the images inside those divs dont overflow their parent you can add this CSS:

```
img {
    max-width: 100%; /* set the max-width to 100% of parent */
    height: auto; /* don't distort the images */
    vertical-align: top; /* remove gap below each image */
}
```

You can have a look a look at this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CG3mm/) to see how it looks.

**EDIT:**
If you don't want four images in a row with a smaller screen size, but just two in a row for instace, you need to use CSS Media Queries and set the width of the inner divs to 50% (50 * 2 = 100).